# Why won't my program print to my GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

This is my code - when I try to run the program though, it won't print/display to the `finalResult` text field in my GUI. Any ideas?

```
 private void calculateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    // Coding:

    int a = 1;

    userInput = minInput.getText();
    int value1 = Integer.parseInt(userInput);

    userInput2 = maxInput.getText();
    int value2 = Integer.parseInt(userInput2);


    while (a <= value1)
   {
        //Print numbers inbetween user's value and 1:

      int square = value1*value1;

        //Print:
        finalResult.setText("" + square);

        //Modifier:
        value1 = value1  + 1;

   }

   for (a = 0; a <= value1; a ++)
   {
        finalResult.setText("" + a*a);
   }


   while (value1 < value2)
   {
        //Print numbers inbetween value 2 and valeu1:

      int square = value2*value2;

        //Print:
        finalResult.setText("" + square);

        //Modifier:
        value2 = value2  + 1;

   }

   for (a = 0; a <= value2; a ++)
   {
        finalResult.setText("" + a*a);
   }
```

Comment: Just to make sure, you are adding the listener to the button right?

Comment: okay I'm going to sound like an idiot here and ask you a probably dumb question: by listener are you referring to like Integer.parseInt or something else (my course isn't very informative)                                                    Edit: I've researched it a bit, do you mean like ActionListener

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, but those for loops loop very fast, so you don't see the changes to the text field as it occurs. Whatever you do, don't use `Thread.sleep(...)` to try to solve this, but instead consider using a Swing Timer in place of those for loops so you can see the interim results.

---

**Edit**
It looks like this loop will never end:

```
while (a <= value1)
```

When will a ever be > value1 inside of the loop?

Same possible issue for the next while loop.

Comment: okay, thanks, but how exactly would I use a swing timer in place? what it seems like right now is that code isn't working since when I click the "Calculate"  button in my GUI it gets "stuck" (I'm far from good at this)

Comment: @user3561829: if it gets stuck then probably one of your while loops isn't stopping. As for how to use a Swing Timer, I suggest that you Google `Java Swing Timer Tutorial` and the first hit will help you. Also to debug your code and to see if an infinite or long running loop is occurring, place some println statements in there. As for `"I'm far from good at this"`, practice will make you better.

Comment: ok, i'll definitely try that, the infinite loops thing is ringing some bells now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see all the output, try using a read-only `JTextArea` like this:

```
javax.swing.JTextArea outputBox = new JTextArea();
outputBox.append("" + square + "\n");
```